# What is the difference between using tf.Session() and @tf.function?

Tags: tensorflow

They both execute the code in graph mode, so why use one over another? I've looked it up, but I can't find a good explanation anywhere!!

Comment: `tf.session()` allows to execute graphs or part of graphs. It allocates resources for that and holds the actual values of intermediate results and variables.Which is default behavior in `Tensorflow 1.x`. `Sessions` are gone in `TensorFlow 2.x`. There is one global runtime in the background that executes all computation, whether run `eagerly` or as a compiled `tf.function`.

Comment: You can use `tf.function` to make graphs out of your programs. It is a transformation tool that creates Python-independent dataflow graphs out of your Python code. `AutoGraph` is a library that is on by default in `tf.function`, and transforms a subset of Python eager code into graph-compatible TensorFlow ops. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function). Thanks!